# $_GET doesn't read by the 2nd page of my php file, but when I try to echo its working

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with `$_GET`. When I click the submit button it doesn't read the "id" which came from my first page of php. This is the link where the value of id came from `<?php echo $content."<p><a href='post.php?id=$pid'>Comment.</a>"?></p>` but when I try to to run this `echo $_GET['id'];` its working at it shows that it has value.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$c = $_GET['id'];
}
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("blog");
?>
<html>
<head>
<body background="u.jpg">
<center>

<a href="register.php"><img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="50"/></a>
<a href="login.php"><img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="50"/></a>
<a href="index.php"><img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="50"/></a>
</center>
<center>
<title>Pinoy Blog</title>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$content = $_POST['content'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (comment,p_id) VALUE('$content','$c')");
echo '<a href="index.php">span style="font-size:26px;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; ">Success! Tignan ang post.&nbsp;</span></strong></span>.</a> 
|| <a href="post.php">Magpost ulit? Click mo to.</a>';
}else{
?>
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
<span style="font-size:26px;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; ">Comment:&nbsp;</span></strong></span>
<textarea name='content' ></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='POST!'/>
</form>
<?php
}
?>

<center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions and at least instead switch to `mysqli_*` functions.  The PHP manual clearly indicates this in a big red box at the top of the page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: i am not clear about the whole scenario. for quick comment, i do not see where you set `$pid = $_GET['id']`! Please indent your code and post all relevant pages and rephrase your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you are coming from first page to second page with link then it's called query string & you will get it in $_GET['id']

2) But now you are on second page & click on submit button it means it is new http request which doesn't carry $_GET values from previous http request. so you need store $_GET['id'] into second page as hidden form field.

Change your php code as below

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
$c = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
```

Now take one hidden field in your form.

```
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
   <span style="font-size:26px;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; ">Comment:&nbsp;</span></strong></span>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'] ?>" name="id">
  <textarea name='content' ></textarea><br />
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='POST!'/>
</form>
```

Note: $_REQUEST default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting a POST form and then searching for GET variables???

To be honest I'm struggling to understand the question, you're saying that when you first land on the page the $_GET['id'] is printing out, but then when you submit the form on that page the ID isn't there??

Comment: no, 'if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$c = $_GET['id'];
}' this is from the first page of my php file which came from this link '<a href='post.php?id=$pid'>Comment.</a>"?>'

Comment: Better use REQUEST array, that you can get both and post and get data

Comment: you say 'when I click submit' so are you or are you not submitting the POST form, cos I can't see any id variable in there.

Comment: do i need to post my 1st page ? Im just a beginner in PHP

Comment: yes put the id var in there as GBD says - <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']" name="id">

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where/when are you `echo`ing the query string value such that it displays?

More to the point, I'm going to assume that the code we're seeing is for `post.php` and that the page is essentially submitting to itself.  I'm also going to assume that when you first load the page, you do so with a query string argument.  Something like this:

```
/path/to/post.php?id=123
```

However, when you submit the form, you change that URL:

```
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
```

Now you're loading something like this:

```
/path/to/post.php
```

There's no more query string value on the URL, so when the PHP code responds to this request it won't have anything in `$_GET['id']`.  You need to include the query string value when submitting the request to the server.  Something like this might work:

```
<form action="post.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?>" method="post">
```

Conversely, instead of mixing `POST` and `GET` values, you could set a hidden field in the form.  Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['id']); ?>" />
```

Then your `form`'s `action` won't have to change, but you would have to change how to access the value in the PHP code.  `$_REQUEST['id']` will pull the value from *either* the GET values *or* the POST values, so it need only be present in one of them.  That way the same array can be used both when first loading the page and when submitting the page back to itself.

Note the use of `htmlspecialchars()` here.  I'm *not* a PHP expert, but what I'm explicitly attempting to do is prevent some cross-site scripting attack whereby the code would blindly echo to the page (on your behalf) user-submitted input, which could be malicious.  `url encode()` may also do the trick.  It's worth further research for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='post.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>' method='post'>
<span style="font-size:26px;"><strong><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; ">Comment:&nbsp;</span></strong></span>
<textarea name='content' ></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='POST!'/>
</form>
```

It Will Post Form To post.php?id=1 or any other
And You Will get Values Of `$_GET['id']`

Replace `action='post.php'` with `action='post.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'`